# The requested module '/path' does not provide an export named file.json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, import, vue-props

I'm expecting to render a json file in a Vue js app, but I'm getting an error The requested module '/path' does not provide an export named file.json. Even though the file exists and is with a correct syntax.

```js
<template>
  <FlightsList :flights="flights"/>
</template>

import { allFlights } from '../modules/api/drafts/flights.json'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      flights: allFlights
    }
  },
```

Comment: Where does the `'/path'` come from? This error message doesn't make much sense if you have another path import

Comment: It is import { file } from '../modules/api/drafts/file.json'